# Creating javascript event listerner

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand and convert the following code into JavaScript, I am guessing it is written in TypeScript so I am trying to understand what is it doing

```
addEventListener("direct-upload:initialize", event => {
  const { target, detail } = event
  const { id, file } = detail
  target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", `
    <div id="direct-upload-${id}" class="direct-upload direct-upload--pending">
      <div id="direct-upload-progress-${id}" class="direct-upload__progress" style="width: 0%"></div>
      <span class="direct-upload__filename">${file.name}</span>
    </div>
  `)
})
```

Here is my try so far

```
addEventListener("direct-upload:initialize", doSomething, false);

function doSomething(e) {
  var target
  var details
}
```

and then I am lost. I will really appreciate if someone can explain it to me what the above code is doing

Comment: It's not TypeScript, it's plain Javascript, but with ES6 features like `=>` and `const`.

Comment: thanks @AndroidNoobie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not TypeScript, it's JavaScript. Specifically, it's JavaScript using features from the ES2015 specification (arrow functions, destructuring assignment, `const`, template literals) and relying on automatic semicolon insertion. Those ES2015 features work on up-to-date modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge); they don't work on any version of IE. Look them up on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for details and contrasts with ES5 and earlier. You can also use [Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=IYExFEDcFMDsBcAyBLAzvO0BOAKARCMltAMbwC0ArgA4A2A9qAFzKzLzLC3IBe0eAGgAE0GAiEBeAHxCA3gCghQkvVjo5Q-MCwBzaPGEh9wZLSEBfSSLHxFy1etlDkIYQDNT0C1aNbTdrV19ADpWVGx4AEEQACtgEjh4AAkAFQBZRHwAI2g3emIcnVZBIQADOyUAHkJIZxAJAiJSChoGUHIAElkXczxlWmBUVAbCYjIqOkYQIVHmibaQcnJqOEJYHTwpCqUhauRalxGm8dap5ax6HWIhzu6QXv7B4caxlsnQAH0P6gur6CG-ugAJ60aANADuLngAAsmEIAAwAUk2lQA9DUtjsdpVUNRgLBHkMjq95lMvh5QbBgABbfhSLoU6DBKm08xo3H4zHY9H7LmlACU8nM_KAA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&version=6.26.0) to convert ES2015+ code to ES5 (though it may rely on polyfills).

In ES5 and earlier it would look something like this:

```
addEventListener("direct-upload:initialize", function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var detail = event.detail;
  var id = detail.id;
  var file = detail.file;
  target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin",
    '<div id="direct-upload-' + id + '" class="direct-upload direct-upload--pending">' +
      '<div id="direct-upload-progress-' + id + '" class="direct-upload__progress" style="width: 0%"></div>' +
      '<span class="direct-upload__filename">' + file.name + '</span>' +
    '</div>'
  );
});
```

---

Side note: These two lines:

```
const { target, detail } = event
const { id, file } = detail
```

...could be written like this:

```
const { target, detail = {id, file} } = event;
```

...since `detail` isn't used for anything other than getting `id` and `file`.